# Check if a node exists using Python

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, node-editor

Is it possible to check to see if a certain node exists on a material from within Python, for example a diffuse node? I am using Cycles Material Nodes, not Blender Internal or Post-Processing.

Comment: Can you be more specific, do you know the name of the node? is diffuse a name or a type of node?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`bpy_prop_collection.get`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection.html#bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection.get) method which acts like pythons `dict.get`.

```
import bpy

mat = bpy.data.materials["MyMaterial"]
if mat.use_nodes:
    ntree = mat.node_tree
    node = ntree.nodes.get("Diffuse BSDF", None)
    if node is not None:
        print("We Found:", node)
```

This is similar to using:

```
node = ntree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"]
```

However if the node isn't found you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through all the nodes in the node tree and check their properties.

For example, to find if a material node tree contains any diffuse shaders, you could do this:

```
import bpy

mat = bpy.data.materials['MyMaterial']
# Test if 'Use Nodes' is enabled:
if mat.use_nodes == True:
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    # Iterate through all the nodes in the node tree and test each one to see if it's a diffuse shader:
    for node in nodes:
        if node.bl_idname == 'ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse':
            # Do stuff
        else:
            # Do other stuff
```

You can test any node property (e.g. `label`, `location`, `name`, etc.), to see a full list check the [API reference](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.types.Node.html).

Comment: I think this can be simplified to: `if 'ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse' in mat.node_tree.nodes:`, No need to check every `bl_idname`.

Comment: @ideasman42 I couldn't get that to work.. Maybe that only works for the `name` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

For example, check if node exists in material nodes by name:

```
if 'Material Output' in [node.name for node in bpy.data.materials['your_material_name'].node_tree.nodes]:
    print('Yes!')
```